# Why blockquote tag does not work in PHP loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, imgur

I am returning data from my db, all data works, except the images, for some reason the blockquote tag is only being printed on the first row, I am using `embed.js` to return Imgur photos and .gifs

**html**

```
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**php**

```
<h1>Fotos e gifs</h1>
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY codigo DESC");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h3>".$res['titulo']."</h3>";
    echo "<blockquote class='imgur-embed-pub' lang='en' data-id='".$res['link_imagem']."'></blockquote>";
    echo "<hr>";
}   
?>
```

Here is what is happening and my db.

[image]

Comment: Because you blockquote is empty. (No data between tags).

Comment: ik, but why the image is not  showing? the embed.js should return the image from imgur like this: ```<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="MY_URL"></blockquote>``` each post have a different url

Comment: Are you including the script after the HTML body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for this, each script supports one blockquote for some reason, i just add to the script tag on while loop like this:

```php
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h3>".$res['titulo']."</h3>";
    echo "<blockquote class='imgur-embed-pub' data-id='".$res['link_imagem']."'></blockquote>"."<script async src='//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js' charset='utf-8'></script>";
    echo "<p>".$res['conteudo']."</p>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```